# Get info card from embed API in API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I like this info card you get in the left top corner of a card you embed. Is there a possibility to display this card if I use the API v3. Or do I have to use the embed API of Google Maps?

Because I like to block the use of the scrollwheel and some other options of the API which I can not use with the embedding API.

[image: Example embedded map]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the Custom Save Widget.

original:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget

archive.org:

> https://web.archive.org/web/20160331182749/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget

the save-widget is going away, but I think the way to show the box should be still valid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Save Widget</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #save-widget {
        width: 300px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Roboto, Arial;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="save-widget">
      <strong>Google Sydney</strong>
      <p>We’re located on the water in Pyrmont, with views of the Sydney Harbour Bridge, The
          Rocks and Darling Harbour. Our building is the greenest in Sydney. Inside, we have a
          "living wall" made of plants, a tire swing, a library with a nap pod and some amazing
          baristas.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      /*
       * This sample uses a custom control to display the SaveWidget. Custom
       * controls can be used in place of the default Info Window to create a
       * custom UI.
       * This sample uses a Place ID to reference Google Sydney. Place IDs are
       * stable values that uniquely reference a place on a Google Map and are
       * documented in detail at:
       * https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid
       */

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: {lat: -33.8666, lng: 151.1958},
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
              google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            ],
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
          }
        });

        var widgetDiv = document.getElementById('save-widget');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(widgetDiv);

        // Append a Save Control to the existing save-widget div.
        var saveWidget = new google.maps.SaveWidget(widgetDiv, {
          place: {
            // ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4 is the place Id for Google Sydney.
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
            location: {lat: -33.866647, lng: 151.195886}
          },
          attribution: {
            source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
            webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
          }
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: saveWidget.getPlace().location
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! Thx. This is basically what I'm looking for. Is there any option to add a Route Planner link above/below the "Save in Google Maps" link? Or do I have to include this link in the widgets HTML by myself?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160331182749/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget